# too many initializers for std::string array

Tags: c++, stdstring

MEA CULPA:

Ok, I was wrong.  I found the declaration of VarInfo::m_datatypeName[] and it was VarInfo::m_datatypeName[9].  Yep, hard coded.  My apologies to all who scratched their heads for me.

---

I receive this error:

```
too many initializers for 'std::string[9]'
```

for this statement:

```
std::string       VarInfo::m_datatypeName[]  = { "", "STRING", "TIME", "MACADDRESS", "IPADDRESS", "STRINGSET", "SET", "UINT32", "INT32", "BOOL" };
```

**NEW INFORMATION:**

NB:  There is no 9 or 10 in the statement.  If there are no more than nine items in the assignment list, this works just fine.  It's item 10th item that is the problem.

**END NEW INFORMATON:**

I have this vague recollection that a std::string declaration preallocates space for some default number of characters so i am want to suspect similar behavior for an array of strings.

So, here is the question.  How should I correctly declare this?  Hopefully without having to hard declare the size of m_datatypenames?

Comment: I suspect the '9' is a big clue here!! :)

Comment: How is `m_datatypeName` defined in the class definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::string m_datatypeName[9]
```

should probably be

```
std::string m_datatypeName[10]
```

`"", "STRING", "TIME", "MACADDRESS", "IPADDRESS", "STRINGSET", "SET", "UINT32", "INT32", "BOOL"` add up to 10 values.

Comment: But there is no 9!  What's magic about 9 (or less) that isn't magic about 10?

Comment: @WesMiller how is `m_datatypeName` declared inside `VarInfo`? In the class definition? Is there a 9 in there?

Comment: It's getting a 9 from somewhere... Have you checked the class VarInfo?

Comment: This is the declaration.

Comment: @WesMiller you can't initialize members inside the class. Post the definition of `VarInfo`.

Comment: You are right.  I misread my code VarInfo::m_datatypeName[9] is declared right there under my nose.  Apologies to all and mea culpa posted in OP.

Answer (score 3):

Declare it as:

```
std::string m_datatypeName[10];
```

as there are ten strings being used to initialise the array, not nine.

If you want to avoid specifying the number of elements you could use a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
struct VarInfo
{
    static std::vector<std::string> m_datatypeName;
};
```

and if C++11 you can use initializer braces (demo at http://ideone.com/mGS9H):

```
std::vector<std::string> VarInfo::m_datatypeName
    {
        "", "STRING", "TIME", "MACADDRESS", "IPADDRESS",
        "STRINGSET", "SET", "UINT32", "INT32", "BOOL"
    };
```

or if not C++11 you can use [`boost::assign::list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of):

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> VarInfo::m_datatypeName =
    boost::assign::list_of
        ("")("STRING")("TIME")("MACADDRESS")("IPADDRESS")
        ("STRINGSET")("SET")("UINT32")("INT32")("BOOL");
```

Comment: There is no 9!  Why do I need 10?

Answer (score 2):

You give 10 parameters for an `std::string[9]`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have this vague recollection that a std::string declaration
>   preallocates space for some default number of characters so i am want
>   to suspect similar behavior for an array of strings.

Uh, no. `T[]` behaves exactly the same, no matter what the type of `T`. If you don't want to use `std::vector` you will have to hardcode the number in the array.